# Limit of an euler product

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Before I can ask my question, I have to state a couple of definitions. 
Let $f$ be a multiplicative function and let
$$
D_f(s) = \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^s},
$$
and define $\Lambda_f(n)$ as follows:
$$
- \frac{D'_f(s)}{D_f(s)} = \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{\Lambda_f(n)}{n^s}.
$$ 
Suppose we have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda_f(n) = c \log x + O(1)
\end{equation}
for some positive constant $c.$

I was reading a textbook and it says that the following Euler product 
$$
\prod_p (1 - p^{-s-1})^c (\sum_{v=0}^{\infty} f(p^v) p^{-vs} )
$$
has limit as $s \rightarrow 0$ by virtue of the above equation (third equation in this question).

I am not quite seeing how the above equation is helpful in getting that the Euler product has a limit as $s \rightarrow 0$. I would appreciate any explanation! Thank you!

Comment: Which book is this from?

Comment: @mixedmath It is from Analytic Number Theory by Iwaniec and Kolwalski. page 27. Thanks!